# I am facing an error in Spring Boot JPA when using custom native select query

Tags: sql, spring, jpa, native

I have created a custom query in my Repository Interface as:

```
@Query(name = "select * from tblusers where first_name like %?1% OR last_name like %?2% OR username like %?3%", nativeQuery = true)
public List<Optional<UsersEntity>> customizedFindUser(String first_name,String last_name,String username);
```

And when I try to compile the project am facing the error as:

> Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List com.beezy.asserttracker.users.UsersRepository.customizedFindUser(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String); Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.beezy.asserttracker.users.UsersRepository.customizedFindUser(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String); No property 'customizedFindUser' found for type 'UsersEntity'

So am confused as to what I have done wrong.

I have tried changing the placeholder numbering as:

```
@Query(name = "select * from tblusers where first_name like %?%1 OR last_name like %?%2 OR username like %?%3", nativeQuery = true)
    public List<Optional<UsersEntity>> customizedFindUser(String first_name,String last_name,String username);
```

And then I have also commented out the code and it the project could compile successfully. So I can't figure out what is wrong here.

Comment: post your entity class as well.

Comment: Hi, the primary cause of the error what that I had made a mistake by putting @Query(name="") instead of @Query(value="") I don't know how I couldn't see that error because I have always used name= all along. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Property `name` of @Query anotation related to named queries. Use `value` instead

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue, didn't even notice that small error.

Answer (score 0):

Add the sql placehoders to the string directly

```
@Query(name = "select * from tblusers where first_name like ?1 OR last_name like ?2 OR username like ?3", nativeQuery = true)
public List<Optional<UsersEntity>> customizedFindUser(String "%" + first_name + "%",String "%" + last_name + "%",String "%" + username + "%");
```